# Vlc opens a second window

Tags: vlc

Soo i have a problem, vlc opens a window. When i  start a song but when it finishes and i want to start another new song vlc opens a new vlc window and i want that it opens at the place of the old one how can i fux this problem ?? If someone can help me please comment so i can understand what is happening. 
And another question , is it illegal to download videos from youtube for free from ytmp3 ? I heard that it’s illegal to have songs free but i don’t think it’s illegal because all my life i used it to download free musics. Im not into this things that apple make. He obliges you to pay for your songs, at the end nothing is free if you look like that the life

Comment: On this site you are supposed to ask one question at a time. I'll answer the VLC question.

Comment: @Jos  sry but i had to write a lot cause he wouldn’t let me post my question if it was too small

Comment: Are you using VLC for music or are they videos?  If it is music, use a tool that is designed for music like Banshee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you click a song in a file manager, VLC will open a new *instance*.

To avoid this, go to Tools/Preferences/Interface Settings and check the boxes next to "Allow only one instance" and "Use only one instance when started from file manager".

Comment: This fix doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 VLC relese 3.0.16. A second window is opened for the video almost always.