# multiple copies of VLC in top bar will not remove

Tags: 20.04, vlc

The top bar of my Ubuntu 20.04 now has 8 tiny little VLC application icons. VLC is very useful, I do not wish to remove it from my machine. It is in my favorites bar at the bottom of my screen, where again it is fine.

I have so far been unable to remove any copies of the icon from the top bar. I have tried, right click, right click with ctrl, with the windows key, with the windows and alt key and any other combinations I can think of. There is never an option to remove it. There is a quit option, but that does not rid me of these.

Also when I use the Settings program, the Volume level shows up seven times "Icon" VLC media player (LibVLC3.0.11).

This is very annoying, though it does not seem to have any other adverse effects.

[image: screen shot showing top of screen with VLC icons]

[image: from settings showing multiple VLCs]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vlc opens a second window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235127/vlc-opens-a-second-window)

Comment: It does not answer my question. It is unrelated.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of this, upload on imgur then edit your question and share the link

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but it's possible that the installation did not go according to plans, at least tht's what's happened to me with VLC.

I resolved with these steps:

1. **Purge VLC**

   ```
   sudo apt purge < complete VLC Package name >
   ```
2. Update packages and install all the needed ones for your version

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```
3. Re-install VLC

   ```
   sudo apt install < complete VLC Package name >
   ```

If you installed with **snap** simply replace step 1 & 3 with corresponding snap commands.

Comment: I have the same problem the VLC doesn't quit and that there eventually are a number of copies, one for every time you want to play something else. The apt purge, update, dist-upgrade and install did not work for me. I tried using snap as well but the problem hasn't gone away.